# XGBOOST scale_pos_weight

Tags: h2o

How do you set the value for `scale_pos_weight` in h2o for XGBOOST?

I have thought about setting weights_column but I am not sure if they are the same thing or not?

Answer (score 0):

In H2O, there is [`balance_classes`](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/balance_classes.html) which helps with resampling your positives/negatives. However, it doesn't seem to be supported for XGBoost yet. Applying a `weights_column` would be a good alternative.